# How do i fix this Npm Error on my terminal on visual studio code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npm init -y
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because the terminal cannot find your `npm` installation. Double check that you have the latest version of Node.js installed as it should also install npm.

To check if Node is installed, run the command `node --version` in your terminal. If it comes up with a similar message "node is not recognized", you may have to reinstall Node which can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

However if the Terminal spits back out the Node version installed on your system, something may have gone wrong during the installation process, so you should still reinstall.

In some cases a computer restart can also solve these types of issues after installation.