# VS Code integrated terminal error while running `npm version patch`

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, npm, terminal

I run the command `npm version patch` in the integrated terminal in VS Code and it fails to run it and this is the log:

```
'add',
info git   'C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\ 
 client\\src\\quickapp\\clientapp\\package.json

'add',
info git   'C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\ 
 client\\src\\quickapp\\clientapp\\package-lock.json

info git [ 'commit', '-m', '1.12.9' ]
```

It tries to stage the files using their **full path** without success, and when it comes to the `commit` part it fails because the files are not staged.

When I run the command from the integrated terminal like this: `git add package.json` it works as expected but with the full path it doesn't.

More Information:
When I run `npm version patch` from git bash it works fine.

What VS Code settings am I missing here?

Comment: which `git --version` is it ? ik it's integrated terminal but is it cmd.exe or powershell.exe or somethingElse.exe ? try **which_shell.ps1**: `(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$((Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$PID).ParentProcessId)).Path`

Comment: where did you get the log from ? my log looks like this: **C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-15T13_33_42_147Z-debug-0.log**: `0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js` 
`1 info using npm@8.15.0` `2 info using node@v16.17.0` `35 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\path\package.json'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VSCode type ctrl+shift+p to open the user preferences and then search for features -> terminal -> cwd and if it has a value you should clear it.

cwd is An explicit start path where the terminal will be launched, this is used as the current working directory (cwd) for the shell process. This may be particularly useful in workspace settings if the root directory is not a convenient cwd.

Comment: Clearing the cwd value fixed that for me, thank you.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense, if the cwd is wrong, `git add package.json` wouldn't work as intended, and the error would be `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`, this doesn't explain why full path fails but relative path succeeds

Comment: @Mr.Doge I don't know how to explain this, but it in fact this is the only thing that worked.

Comment: @Offir "When I run the command from the integrated terminal like this: `git add package.json` it works as expected but with the full path it doesn't." you didn't include the error message, or say that there was no error message, the git error message should tell you a lot about why git didn't add, reproduce it please (full path failing), I'm not able to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

It might not answer your question but it should solve the issue.

You could use git bash as vscode terminal as describe here : https://blog.danielpadua.dev/posts/git-bash-with-vscode/

Comment: I tried and it didn't make any difference. –

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps vsCode does not have the right permissions?
What happens if you run vsCode as administrator?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change VScode terminal to git bash like in the picture ?
Integrated terminals can be different. if it isnt visible @bieboebap answer can add the gitbash to your integrated terminal.

[image: IMG]

And for npm commands you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651358/how-do-i-fix-this-npm-error-on-my-terminal-on-visual-studio-code) question.

Comment: I tried and it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

update git to `2.37.3` currently https://git-scm.com/download/win
git add using fullPath is supposed to work

`git --version`
`git version 2.37.3.windows.1`

operating system: I assume windows because `\\`

Comment: git version: `git version 2.37.3.windows.1`